# transformIgnorePatterns not working after update to jest 24

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I just updated to jest 24 and it seems like `transformIgnorePatterns` does not work.

this is the error I receive:

```
/Users/lemoustachiste/work/frontend/node_modules/my-untranspiled-package/build/bundle.js:7948
    export default Package$1;
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

jest config:

```
module.exports = {
  'modulePaths': [
    '<rootDir>/src/',
    '<rootDir>/node_modules'
  ],
  'transformIgnorePatterns': [
    'node_modules/(?!(my-untranspiled-package)/)'
  ],
  'transform': {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(scss|ico)$': '<rootDir>/tests/importStub.js'
  },
  'setupFiles': [
    '<rootDir>/tests/jest-aurelia.config.ts'
  ],
  'setupFilesAfterEnv': ['<rootDir>/tests/jest-framework.config.ts'],
  'testRegex': '\\.(test|spec)\\.(ts|js)x?$',
  'globals': {
    'ts-jest': {
      'diagnostics': false
    }
  }
};
```

The project is still configured for babel 6. It is working fine with Jest 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I started by updating to babel 7 but still encountered the issue.
I then found this comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7578#issuecomment-451671656

which pointed to this part of the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel

And sure enough, extracting the babel config to its own file out of the package.json fixed the issue.